# Qt temporarily fullscreen

Tags: c++, qt

Il would like to make a widget go into fullscreen temporarily and come back to it's original place, like in the following question : [Qt Widget temporarily fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338548/qt-widget-temporarily-fullscreen).
The problem is that my widget is in a QTabWidgets so it doen't really have any parents.
I tried this code but it doesn't work

The widget which goes in fullscreen :

```
void WebPage::setFullScreen(QWebEngineFullScreenRequest request)
{
    if(request.toggleOn()) {
        setParent(nullptr);
        showFullScreen();
        request.accept();
    }
    else {
        showMaximized();
        emit resetFullscreen(this);
        request.accept();
    }
}
```

The QTabWidgets:

```
connect(page, SIGNAL(resetFullscreen(QWidget*)), m_tabs, SLOT(setCurrentWidget(QWidget*)));
```

WebPage is the class for the object I want to put in fullscreen, page is an object from this class and m_tabs is the object which contains page.

Edit:
m_tabs is the QTabWidgets and WebPage inherits QWebEngineView

Edit:
the WebPage parent isn't the QTabWidget but a string like "qtabwidget_something"

Do you have any solution ?

Comment: Could you tell us who is page, WebPage, m_tabs? and like these relationships, your current description is confusing.

Comment: Does WebPage inherit from a particular class?

Comment: m_tabs is the QTabWidget?

Comment: So what exactly is not working with your code? A widget inside a QTabWidget will automatically get the QTabWidget as parent. (Have a look at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#removeTab)